# glUniformMatrix4dv with a unidimensional array

Tags: opengl, c++, c

I am trying to convert this C++ gml code to C and am getting the same array but I cannot see anything on the screen, is there something I am doing wrong maybe on the shader?

GML code in C++:

```
GLuint MatrixID = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "MVP");
...
glm::mat4 MVP = Projection * View * Model;
printf("MVP:\n");
for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
  for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
    printf("%.2f\n",MVP[i][j]);  //prints the same list as in C
...
//durante el loop
glUniformMatrix4fv(MatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &MVP[0][0]); //draw a cube
```

C code:

```
GLuint MatrixID = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "MVP");
...
t_mat4 MVP;  //t_mat4 defined as typedef double t_mat4[16];
mulMatrix(Projection,View,MVP);
mulMatrix(MVP,Model,MVP);
printf("proj*view*model\n");
inrange(i,16)
    printf("%.2f\n",MVP[i]); //unidimensional array
...
//durante el loop
glUniformMatrix4dv(MatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, MVP); //Nothing shows up
```

vertex shader:

```
#version 330 core

// Input vertex data, different for all executions of this shader.
layout(location = 0) in vec3 vertexPosition_modelspace;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 vertexColor;

// Output data ; will be interpolated for each fragment.
out vec3 fragmentColor;
// Values that stay constant for the whole mesh.
uniform mat4 MVP;

void main(){    

    // Output position of the vertex, in clip space : MVP * position
    gl_Position =  MVP * vec4(vertexPosition_modelspace,1);

    // The color of each vertex will be interpolated
    // to produce the color of each fragment
    fragmentColor = vertexColor;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> glUniformMatrix4dv(MatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, MVP); //Nothing shows up

This will yield an OpenGL `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` error. The reason being that the `MatrixID` variable is of type `mat4`, which is a *`float`* matrix, not a `dmat4` (which, BTW, is not supported in GLSL 3.30). You almost certainly meant `4fv`.

And of course, your C code should be using `float` arrays, not `double`s.

Comment: ok, I'm not sure why but the cgml library only uses double types. Thank you by the way.